# Showing the ideal generated by these three elements of a ring contains $1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$R$ is a commutative ring with unity. $a$, $b$ and $c$ are elements in $R$ such that there exists $x$, $y$ and $z$ in $R$ such that $xa+by+cz=1$. We denote $a^{15}=d$, $b^{16}= e$, and $c^{17}=f$. Show that there exist $l$, $m$ and $n$ belonging to $R$ such that $ld+me+nf=1$.

The ideal generated by $a,b,c$ contains $1$. I am trying to show that the ideal generated by $d,e,f$ contains$~1$, but I have made no progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here's a more elementary argument  . . .

Let $J = (d,e,f) = (a^{15},b^{16},c^{17})$ be the ideal generated by $d,e,f$.

The goal is to show $J=(1)$.

It's given that $ax + by + cz = 1$, for some $x,y,z \in R$.

Then
\begin{align}
 &a^{15},b^{16},c^{17} \in J\\[4pt]
 \implies\; &(ax + by + cz)^{46} \in J\\[4pt]
 &\qquad\text{[consider the terms in the multinomial expansion]}\\[4pt]
 \implies\; &1 \in J\\[4pt]
 \implies\; &J=(1)\\[4pt]
 \end{align}

as was to be shown.

Answer (score 2):

Let $J = (d,e,f)$ be the ideal generated by $d,e,f$.

The goal is to show $J=(1)$.

Suppose instead that $J$ is a proper ideal of $R$.

Let $M$ be a maximal ideal containing $J$. Then $M$ is a prime ideal, hence

$$a^{15} \in J \implies a^{15} \in M \implies a \in M$$
$$b^{16} \in J \implies b^{16} \in M \implies b \in M$$
$$c^{17} \in J \implies c^{17} \in M \implies c \in M$$

But then $a,b,c \in M \implies 1 \in M$, contradiction.

It follows that $J = (1)$, as was to be shown.

Comment: how do i know that J is contained in a maximal ideal?

Comment: Every proper ideal can be extended to a maximal ideal.

Comment: That's a theorem which you should already have.

Comment: It's proved by a standard application of Zorn's lemma.

Comment: I dont know zorn's lemma. is there any other way you can show me that J is contained in a maximal ideal?

Comment: What level of course is this for? What textbook?

Comment: this is an exam question for a phd exam, im an undergrad

Comment: @tony No there is no other way to show that $J$ is contained in a maximal ideal, but there might be another way to answer your question without depending on Zorn's lemma.

Comment: Well, if the question is for a Ph.D. qualifying exam, it's assumed that the student knows Zorn's lemma and has seen proofs via Zorn's lemma of the fact that in a commutative ring with 1, any proper ideal can be extended to a maximal ideal.

Comment: ok, i understand the rest of the explaination though.

Comment: What textbook are you using for your course?

Comment: i am self studying from basic algebra by nathan jacobson

Comment: what is a good book to  study zorn's lemma?

Comment: That theorem (about extending proper ideals to maximal ones) should be in that book. Also, a discussion of Zorn's lemma should also be somewhere in that book. Check the index.

Comment: can we use polynomials over R having three indeterminates. where the first indeterminate maps to 'a', the second maps to b, and the third maps to c.

Comment: i will check it

Comment: I just checked; the discussion of Zorn's lemma is done in Volume 2.

Comment: i just read understood zorn's lemma from artin and applied it to this problem. I understand your solution fully now. thanks for taking time out to provide me with  2 different solutions.

Answer (score 2):

It is obvious that $1 \in I \Longleftrightarrow 1 \in \sqrt{I}$ holds, because $1^n=1$ for all $n$. This immediately answers the question.

Comment: what is sqrt I?

Comment: So you have accepted my answer, but you dont even know all the tools I used? $$\sqrt{I} = \{ r \in R | r^n \in I \text{ for some } n \}$$

Comment: im operating from smart phone, must have pressed by mistake.

Comment: I admit, I didn't fully see how your proof worked at first (it seemed too short!, and I don't always see things instantly). But your proof is fine, modulo the assumption that the reader knows the definition of rad(I) and the fact that it's an ideal.

Answer (score 1):

**Claim**: Suppose $a,a',b,c\in R$ satisfy $(a,b,c) = (a',b,c) = R$. Then $(aa',b,c) = R$.

**Proof**: We have $ax = 1-by-cz$ and $a'x' = 1-by'-cz'$ for some $x,x',y,y',z,z'\in R$, so multiplying gives
$$aa'xx' = 1 - b(y+y'-byy') - c(z+z'-czz') + bc(yz'+y'z),$$
so $aa'x''+by''+cz'' = 1$ for $x'' = xx'$, $y'' = y+y'-byy'-c(yz'+y'z)$, and $z'' = z+z'-czz'$.$\square$

Hence, if $(a,b,c) = R$, applying the above claim to $a' = a^n$ for $n\ge 1$ shows, by induction, that $(a^n,b,c) = R$ for all $n\ge 1$. Similar logic shows that $(a^n,b^{n'},c^{n''}) = R$ for all $n,n',n''\ge 1$.